# Performance boost through branch prediction or cache?

Tags: c++, performance

I had to rewrite code so that i get at least 20% more performance.
First we got one virtual class fruits. 
Oranges (o) and Apples (a) inherit from fruits.
new Oranges an Apples were stored in one vector of fruits so I separated both that both has there own vector.

First i thought it's because of the branch prediction because they are kind of sorted but I also read thats because of the cache line,  because same objects are on the same line.

new code:

```
     double run_experiment(const std::vector<Fruit *> &a, const std::vector<Fruit *> &o, int repeats, int checksum) {
    int total = 0;
    Timer timer;
    timer.start();
    std::cout<<"Size A: " << a.size()<< std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Size O: " << o.size()<< std::endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < repeats; k++) {


        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

            total += a[i]->seeds();

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < o.size(); j++) {

            total += o[j]->seeds();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "total out " << total << std::endl;
    timer.stop();
    assert(total == checksum * repeats);
    return timer.seconds();
}
```

old:

```
    double run_experiment(const std::vector<Fruit*>& data, int repeats, int checksum)
{
    int total = 0;
    Timer timer;
    timer.start();
    for (int r = 0; r < repeats; ++r)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
        {
            total += data[i]->seeds();
        }
    }
    timer.stop();
    assert(total == checksum * repeats);
    return timer.seconds();
}
```

where size is 10 000, yes the big loop has to be...

Comment: `const std::vector<Apple> &a, const std::vector<Orange> &o` Using indirection will always kill your performance.

Comment: It's about cache locality. Try a vector of std::variant instead of pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
If I use no Indirection i have to return the array probably?
With std::veriant i don't need to "cast" to apple or oranges if i read it correctly?